# Is it possible to fetch_object while using bind_param? (PHP/MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a question for you guys. I'm trying to make the way that I run MySQL as secure as I can. I'm currently wondering if it's possible to fetch an object with MySQLi after I have prepared the statement, binded the parameters, and executed the statement.

Example:

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?;');
$sql->bind_param('s', $username);

$username = 'RastaLulz';

$sql->execute();
$object = $sql->fetch_object();
echo $object->mail;
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProCMS\DevBestCMS\inc\global\class.mysql.php on line 23
```

However, when I add "$sql->result_metadata();" I don't get an error, but it doesn't return a result (it's just NULL).

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?;');
$sql->bind_param('s', $username);

$username = 'RastaLulz';

$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->result_metadata();
$object = $result->fetch_object();
echo $object->mail;
```

This is how you'd do it without binding the parameters:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'RastaLulz';");
$object = $sql->fetch_object();
echo $object->mail;
```

Here's my current MySQL class - just need to get the execute function working.
http://uploadir.com/u/lp74z4

Any help is and will be appreciated!

Comment: What's in `$username` *before* the bind?  `bind_param` works by reference, and it's quite possible that you're effectively passing nothing into the bind unless `$username` already contains a value (even if it's the wrong value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just dug around in my Database class and this is how I do it. Honestly I don't remember why I needed to do it this way and there might be a much better way. But if it helps you here is the code. I do vaguely remember being irritated about there not being a simple way to get your results as an object.

```
// returns an array of objects
public function stmtFetchObject(){

    $rows=array(); //init

    // bind results to named array
    $meta = $this->stmt->result_metadata();
    $fields = $meta->fetch_fields();

    foreach($fields as $field) {
            $result[$field->name] = "";
            $resultArray[$field->name] = &$result[$field->name];
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($this->stmt, 'bind_result'), $resultArray);

    // create object of results and array of objects
    while($this->stmt->fetch()) {
            $resultObject = new stdClass();

            foreach ($resultArray as $key => $value) {
                $resultObject->$key = $value;
            }

            $rows[] = $resultObject;
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, implemented this once I found out my production server was still on 5.3 and get_results() was not available. Note this function returns an array of objects. So if there is one result return $rows[0] to pass the actual object back. ~ Jacob

Comment: Glad it helped. I added a comment to state the return type.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question. I found out that I could do the following:

```
# prepare statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)

# bind params
$stmt->bind_param("s", $param);

# execute query
$stmt->execute();

# get result
$result = $stmt->get_result();

# fetch object
$object = $result->fetch_object();
```

I hope that works for you, too.

Comment: Wanted to add that get_result() is only available in >= 5.3

Comment: get_result() requires the mysqlnd driver to be loaded. As @Jeremiah says it's supposed to be available for install in >= 5.3 and available by default in >=5.4 but I have found instances where it was not available so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I shal verify that years later the lack of mysqlnd (mysql native driver for the mysqli extention in the php build - see phpinfo -> Configure Command) in popular hosts still exists to this day and is just as disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

What is the ';' at the end of your statement? You are giving mysqli an invalid query and so it is not creating an object for you. 
The problem is not the fetch_object, but the prepare statement.
Remove the ';' and try again. It should work like a charm.

---

I've never seen a query end like that. 
Try instantiating the variable before binding.
I think its just good practice but use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: That's the end of the SQL query. I removed it, and the same issue presides.

Comment: A semicolon is required at the end of MySQL queries. When calling them from php they are allowed to be omitted, but AFAIK they don't hurt anything. If you try to perform a query from the sql console without the ending semicolon nothing will happen since it has know way of knowing you've reached the end of the query.

Comment: Yes, I know that. but for php queries, I know you shouldn't use them. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
states that, "The query string should not end with a semicolon."