# PHP MySQLi bind_param() Confusion

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Long story short, I've gotten this far:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_GET['slug']);
```

But I'm completely confused on how to get the result into an associative array. I tried

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->bind_param("s",$_GET['slug']);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["website_name"], $row["subheading"]);
}
```

I don't think I could use `$mysqli->query($query)` instead of a prepared statement, 'cause that seems like it would leave me open to SQL Injection attacks. Yet, that's the bit of code used in the PHP documentation for doing what I want to do. So I can't find anything that shows how to take the results of a prepared statement and move it into an associative array. Does anyone know? Is it even possible?

Comment: First things first - you have to execute the query after you bind your parameters. --> http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to fetch\_object while using bind\_param? (PHP/MySQLi)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287298/is-it-possible-to-fetch-object-while-using-bind-param-php-mysqli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysqli has two ways of doing queries.

You can use prepared statements, where you use `bind_param` to fill in the placeholders, `execute()` to perform the query, and `bind_result` to receive the results.

Or you can use statements with variables interpolated, like mysql. Then you can use `fetch_assoc` to receive the results into an associative array.

I don't think you can mix these two approaches. You can't bind the parameters and then use a fetch function to receive results. If you want that ability, use PDO instead.

It's annoying, IMHO.

Comment: yeah, i'd recommend switching to pdo if at all possible - there's no reason not to, really.

Comment: Thanks! I'm definitely switching over to PDO then.

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli has two ways of getting results out of prepared statement.

- [sane, but not guaranteed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)
- [insane, but guaranteed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#82742)